# Python code inside django to print current copyright year

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

If i am writing the below html code to print the current year for my django project it is printing the whole content instead of the year only.

```
<p>©Copyright xyz {% new "Y"  %}</p>
```

Output should be :

```
©Copyright xyz {% new "Y"  %}
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you meant to use the built-in template tag `now`, you wrote `new`.

Change `{% new "Y" %}` to `{% now "Y" %}` and it should output the current year.

Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#now

Comment: @SatyaranjanBehera Glad I could help!